# "<Comment: >" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used?

Tags: django, many-to-many

I'm new to use (many-to-many) relationship,
I need to allow the users can leave the comment on the user post. this site looks like Quora or StackOverflow the user should signup to get the questions field to put his question and other users whose in site can leave there comments.
 so, how can I continue by adding (add) in (many-to-many) or the real question is: how can I add a comment by (many-to-many) in this code
if anyone help me to complete this issue, please.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_list_or_404
from .forms import UserAskingForm, CommentForm
from .models import UserAsking, Comment
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


@login_required
def user_asking(request):
    form = UserAskingForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserAskingForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.userprofile)
        if form.is_valid():
            asking = form.save(commit=False)
            asking.title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            asking.question = form.cleaned_data['question']
            asking.field = form.cleaned_data['field']
            asking = UserAsking.objects.create(userprofile=request.user.userprofile,
                                               title=asking.title,
                                               question=asking.question,
                                               field=asking.field)
            asking.save()
            return redirect('community:user_questions')
    else:
        form = UserAskingForm()
        return render(request, 'community/asking_question.html', {'form': form})

    return render(request, 'community/asking_question.html', {'form': form})


@login_required
def user_questions(request):
    all_objects = UserAsking.objects.all().order_by('-title')
    all_objects = get_list_or_404(all_objects)
    return render(request, 'community/user_questions.html', {'all_objects': all_objects})


def question_view(request, user_id):
    my_question = UserAsking.objects.get(pk=user_id) # question number e.g '1' for user 'medoabdin'
    comment_form = CommentForm

    if request.method == 'GET':
        comment_form = comment_form(request.GET)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            comments = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            comments.comment = comment_form.cleaned_data['comment']
            # comments is the value of data
            comments.userasking.add()
            #users = User.objects.filter(username=request.user) # medoabdin
            #comments = Comment.objects.create(userasking=my_question, comment=comments)
            #comments.userasking.set(users)
            #comments.userasking.add(*users)

    return render(request, 'community/question_view.html', {'my_question': my_question, 'comment_form': comment_form})
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from account.models import UserProfile
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

CHOICE = [('Technology', 'Technology'), ('Computer Science', 'Computer Science'),
          ('Lawyer', 'Lawyer'), ('Trading', 'Trading'),
          ('Engineering', 'Engineering'), ('Life Dialy', 'Life Dialy')
]


class UserAsking(models.Model):
    userprofile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, help_text='Be specific and imagine you’re asking a question to another person')
    question = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=False, help_text='Include all the information someone would need to answer your question')
    field = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=CHOICE, default='Technology', help_text='Add the field to describe what your question is about')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Comment(models.Model):
    userasking = models.ManyToManyField(UserAsking)
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import UserAsking, Comment


class UserAskingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(required=True,
                            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Type Your Title...',
                                                          'class': 'form-control',
                                                          'data-placement': 'top',
                                                          'title': 'type your title',
                                                          'data-tooltip': 'tooltip'
                                                          }),
                            help_text='Be specific and imagine you’re asking a question to another person')
    question = forms.CharField(required=True,
                               widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder': 'Type Your Details Of Your Question...',
                                                            'class': 'form-control',
                                                            'data-placement': 'top',
                                                            'title': 'type your question simply',
                                                            'data-tooltip': 'tooltip'
                                                            }),
                               help_text='Include all the information someone would need to answer your question')

    class Meta:
        model = UserAsking
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['userprofile']


class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    comment = forms.CharField(max_length=500, required=False, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder': 'Type your comment simply',
                                                                                           'class': 'form-control'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['comment']
```

Answer (score 2):

You first *save* the object to the database, before you can use it in a relation:

```
def question_view(request, user_id):
    my_question = UserAsking.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    comment_form = CommentForm
    if request.method == 'GET':
        comment_form = comment_form(request.GET)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            comments = comment_form.save()
            comments.userasking.add(my_question)
    # …
```

That bein said, I find it rather odd that a `Question` has a many-to-many relation to a `UserAsking`. That thus means that the same comment can be related to multiple `UserAsking` objects?

Comment: I did a relation linked with UserAsking to make permissions for all users to create comments. in this case, every single user will have many comments to do in the same question... if you see another correct way I would hear .. I did what you say but in every time i do reload. the page creates new comments how can I stop that?